# Json data fetch fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am building a shopping cart using a static `JSON` file as the data source. Now when my data is fetched, only the images render as opposed to the other data such as prices and text like the product name.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('feed.json')
        .done(function(data) {
            // Define wine bottle Variables.
            var allBooks = [];
            var x = 0;
            $.each(data.books, function(key, value) {
                x++;
                allBooks.push(
                    "<div class='col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4 thumbnail products'>" +
                    "<h3>" + data.books[key].title + "</h3>" + "<img class='bottles' src='" + data.books[key].imageUrl + "'>" + "<p id='" + x + "'>$" + data.books[key].price + ".00</p>" + "<input type='button' class='" + x + " btn btn-success' value='Add to Cart'>" + "</div>"
                );
            });

            var emptyCart = document.createElement("input");
            emptyCart.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-danger empty");
            emptyCart.setAttribute("type", "button");
            emptyCart.setAttribute("value", "Empty Cart");
            var empty = document.getElementById("empty");
            empty.appendChild(emptyCart);
            $("#books").html(allBooks);

            // Cart functionality
            $('#empty').hide();
            var myCart = 0;
            var price = 0;
            var cartContent = document.getElementById("cartContent");
            var cartValue = document.getElementById("cartValue");

            var priceArr = [];
            cartContent.innerHTML = myCart;
            cartValue.innerHTML = "$ " + price + ".00";

            $(".0").click(function() {
                var item = document.getElementById(0).innerHTML;
                priceArr.push(parseFloat(item.substring(1, item.length)));
                price = priceArr.reduce(function(prev, current) {
                    return prev + current
                })
                $('#empty').fadeIn(300);
                myCart = priceArr.length;
                cartContent.innerHTML = myCart;
                cartValue.innerHTML = "$ " + price + ".00";
            });
            $(".1").click(function() {
                var item = document.getElementById(1).innerHTML;
                priceArr.push(parseFloat(item.substring(1, item.length)));
                price = priceArr.reduce(function(prev, current) {
                    return prev + current
                })
                $('#empty').fadeIn(300);
                myCart = priceArr.length;
                cartContent.innerHTML = myCart;
                cartValue.innerHTML = "$ " + price + ".00";
            });
            $(".2").click(function() {
                var item = document.getElementById(2).innerHTML;
                priceArr.push(parseFloat(item.substring(1, item.length)));
                price = priceArr.reduce(function(prev, current) {
                    return prev + current
                })
                $('#empty').fadeIn(300);
                myCart = priceArr.length;
                cartContent.innerHTML = myCart;
                cartValue.innerHTML = "$ " + price + ".00";
            });
            $(".3").click(function() {
                var item = document.getElementById(3).innerHTML;
                priceArr.push(parseFloat(item.substring(1, item.length)));
                price = priceArr.reduce(function(prev, current) {
                    return prev + current
                })
                $('#empty').fadeIn(300);
                myCart = priceArr.length;
                cartContent.innerHTML = myCart;
                cartValue.innerHTML = "$ " + price + ".00";
            });

            // empty cart
            $("#empty").click(function() {
                myCart = 0;
                price = 0;
                priceArr = [];
                cartContent.innerHTML = myCart;
                cartValue.innerHTML = "$ " + price + ".00";
                $("#empty").fadeOut(400);
            })
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
            console.log("error" + error)
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("finished")
        });
})
```

And here is my static `JSON`:

```
{
    "books":[
        {
            "title": "Brediecker",
            "price": 23,
            "imageUrl": "images/wine.png"
        },
        {
            "title": "Chardonnay",
            "price": 19,
            "imageUrl": "images/growse.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "Gewurztraminer",
            "price": 26,
            "imageUrl": "images/riesling.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "Pinot",
            "price": 215,
            "imageUrl": "images/pinot.jpg"
        },
        {
             "title": "Pinot",
             "price": 215,
             "imageUrl": "images/pinot.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing in order to render the rest of `JSON` data?

Comment: what is error you are getting

Comment: No error, I just can see all the data from the json. Only images are being shown. The rest of the data doesnt render

Comment: put a `debugger` before `allBooks.push(` then check the each value is coming or not.

Comment: How do i go about that? Using a debugger

Comment: just put the word  debugger;  in the source code.  The browser will then stop and you can use the inspector etc.

Comment: I still cant  see an error

Comment: debugger; is not meant to show an error, but pause your browser so you can use the inspector.  What browser you using,..?

Comment: Also in your $.each function your doing  data.books[key].title,  it would be much nicer if you did value.title instead.

Comment: Still all the data doesnt show. Only the imag gets shown

Comment: Please add your html to the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/62etf091/

Comment: The data seems to appear at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1e7n1y0/1/)? have you checked the received object?

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the fields over value.title, value.price etc.

```
 var allBooks = [];
 var x = 0;
 $.each(data.books, function(key, value) {
   x++;
   allBooks.push(
     "<div class='col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4 thumbnail products'>" +
     "<h3>" + value.title + "</h3>" + "<img class='bottles' src='" + value.imageUrl + "'>" + "<p id='" + x + "'>$" + value.price + ".00</p>" + "<input type='button' class='" + x + " btn btn-success' value='Add to Cart'>" + "</div>"
   );
 });
```

Here is a jsFiddle to play around: https://jsfiddle.net/tqxLaom7/2/ 
You can see the output in the console.

You should check the object you get with the debugging tools of your browser.
Here is a general explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_debugging.asp

Depending on the Browser you use you can read more about how to use the developer tools.